# Pandas: vlookup type search to get average/mean values of same name/id items from multiple columns in a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, vlookup

I have a data frame with names and values for items as shown below for two weeks. Some of the item names in week 1 and 2  aren't same

```
week1        week2        
Name Value Name Value 
a     0.1    b  0.6
b     0.3    a  0.3
c     0.5    d  0.1
d     0.7    e  0.4
```

What I am trying to do is create a table that has all names and average values in my final list as shown below. Also, say if item d is not in week 2 then the average should be divided by1 and not 2 something like a dynamic average

```
Name  Average_Value
a      avg from wk1 and 2
b      avg from wk1 and 2
c      avg from wk1 and 2
d          "
e          "
```

I am thinking of using outer join to get the final table by creating two data frames for week1 and week2 values but not sure if creating two separate data frames is a good choice(doing it as not sure if join can be performed if all values are in the same data frame). What can be a better way do approach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack on level 0 column MultiIndex by [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with `level=0` for `week1` / `week2`.  Then group by `Name` using [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and take the [`.mean()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) on `Value`, as follows:

```
(df.stack(level=0)
   .groupby('Name')['Value'].mean()
   .reset_index(name='Average_Value')
)
```

On grouping by `name` and take `mean` on the group, if there are 2 values in the group, it will take the average of 2 values.  If only 1 value, the average will be the value itself.

**Result:**

```
  Name  Average_Value
0    a           0.20
1    b           0.45
2    c           0.50
3    d           0.40
4    e           0.40
```

**Input Setup**

```
data = {('week1', 'Name'): ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        ('week1', 'Value'): [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7],
        ('week2', 'Name'): ['b', 'a', 'd', 'e'],
        ('week2', 'Value'): [0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: tried resetting the column names for 4 weeks of data in the dataframe as:  df.columns =[('week1', 'Name'),('week1', 'Value'), ('week2', 'Name'),('week2', 'Value'),('week3', 'Name'),('week3', 'Value'),('week4', 'Name'),('week4', 'Value')]. However, df.stack(level=0) is not creating two columns for Name and Value, instead I am getting a single column with name and values together. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: @jaeson  What do you mean by resetting the column names by that command ?  Have you properly created 4 sets of 2 columns of data like my input Setup above ?   I run 4 sets of 2 columns data without problem.

Comment: @jaeson  You can create the 4 sets of 2 columns data by e.g.:  `data = {('week1', 'Name'): ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        ('week1', 'Value'): [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7],
        ('week2', 'Name'): ['b', 'a', 'd', 'e'],
        ('week2', 'Value'): [0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4],
        ('week3', 'Name'): ['c', 'a', 'd', 'e'],
        ('week3', 'Value'): [0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4],
        ('week4', 'Name'): ['b', 'a', 'f', 'e'],
        ('week4', 'Value'): [0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4],      
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

Comment: @jaeson  Break the codes above into 2 lines, of course.  With `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` on the second line.   Run my code, and you will see it gives 2 columns as expected.

Comment: I am getting the dataframe reading an excel file which has 4 weeks of data with Name and Value for each week (not creating on my own). I am renaming the column name of that excel as I mentioned earlier and then trying to use  '(df.stack(level=0)
   .groupby('Name')['Value'].mean()
   .reset_index(name='Average_Value')
)'   When I create df  the way you suggested it works but when I read excel and try to implement on my own don't get the desired results.

Comment: when I read excel there are already 4 sets of 2columns for each week .

Comment: @jaeson  In this way, you have to use another method to create the multi-index column labels.  You can use:  `df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['week1', 'week2', 'week3', 'week4'], ['Name', 'Value']])`   The way you defined it previously will only define single level column labels each in form of a tuple rather than real multi-index columns.

Comment: @jaeson You should have seen from the output of your tried code of creating Multi-Index column labels that the result was not getting the Multi-Index as you showed in the very early layout of your question. So, your follow-up question should be asking why your tried code didn't get your expected result. But that is unrelated to the original question and totally not the case the solution didn't produce your expected result. It's only you can't turn your raw data into a format set out in the question.  Anyway, it's fine everything clear now.